# Flutter - Dart - Reflectable package : how to: get class fields type? instantiate object from class/Type? set fields values using Reflectable

Tags: flutter, dart

I came to know that dart mirrors is disabled in flutter but hope that there might be some alternate way to achieve. Mirrors must not be disabled in flutter, it is an important & must have feature.

```
import 'package:reflectable/mirrors.dart';
import 'package:reflectable/reflectable.dart';

const reflector = const Reflector();

class Reflector extends Reflectable
{
  const Reflector() : super(
    invokingCapability,
    typingCapability,
    reflectedTypeCapability,
  );
}

@reflector
class Dictionary
{
  String english, myLang;
  int index;
}

main() { 
   test(); 
}

test()
{
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflector.reflectType(Dictionary);

  classMirror.declarations.values.forEach((field)
  {
    VariableMirror variableMirror = field;
    /*??????????????????????????????????????????
    Now How To Get Field types i.e. String & int
    How to instantiate class object
    How to set fields values
    ???????????????????????????????????????????*/
  });
}
```

Comment: It is the opinion of the Flutter development team that anything you can do with reflection can be done by other means (albeit sometimes with a fair amount of complexity and boilerplate). Case in point, the reflector package achieves its goal using code generation to replicate the functionality. Maybe if you could describe what it is you are wanting to use reflection for, you could get suggestions on how to achieve it in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Runtime object instantiation:***

Use the method newInstance from ClassMirror. The first argument is the constructor name. Like you haven't name constructors, simple pass an empty string. The second argument are an array of positional constructor arguments. No constructor, empty array.

```
   Dictionary dic = classMirror.newInstance("", []);
```

***Set fields values:***

Use the method invokeSetter from InstanceMirror. The first argument is the field name and the second is the value.

```
InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflector.reflect(dic);
instanceMirror.invokeSetter("index", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I am able to know field(s) type:

```
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflector.reflectType(Dictionary);
  VariableMirror variableMirror = classMirror.declarations["english"] as VariableMirror;

  Type type = variableMirror.dynamicReflectedType;
  print("field: " + variableMirror.simpleName + " has type: " + type.toString());
```

Now remaining:
Runtime object instantiation?
How to set fields value of instantiated object?